# Using mail-templated for Django, how do I NOT display a bullet at the end of my sent emails?

Tags: python, django, email, templating

UPDATE:

### This appears to be a feature of my company's email since the dot does not appear in hotmail received emails on mobiles or desktops, or in apple mail on mobiles to non company email accounts.  We are investigating.

Using this as the file 'my_email.tpl':

Please note that mail_templated's base.tpl can be found here:
https://github.com/artemrizhov/django-mail-templated/tree/master/mail_templated/templates/mail_templated

```
{% extends "mail_templated/base.tpl" %}

{% block subject %}
    Some subject 
{% endblock %}

{% block html %}
T
{% endblock %}
```

I send an email with this code:

```
from mail_templated import send_mail

email = 'somearbitraryemailaddress@hotmail.com'

send_mail('my_email.tpl',
          {'user': email},
          'noreply@somecompany.com',
          [email],
          fail_silently=False)
```

I have to have something in the HTML block or I get a character encoding error, hence the letter 'T' - However, my issue is that no matter what I put in the HTML block I always get a bullet or full stop at the end of the email.  I don't want that as it looks rubbish and badly formatted.  Furthermore, the bullet is huge on mobile phone email screens and looks absolutely awful.

Please can someone advise as to how to remove this bullet which I didn't ask for?

Thanks very much.

Comment: If you remove the  from the subject?... also can you add the `base.tpl` code to your question?

Comment: What character encoding error? *Why* do you need anything there? What does the base.tpl look like, especially the html block ?

Comment: Removing the fancy rocket character and replacing it with 'some text' still produces 'T . '

Comment: @DanielRoseman, the HTML block simply contains the letter T in this example.  It actually doesn't matter in the slightest what you place in the HTML block, you still get the annoying bullet/full stop character at the end of the subject body.

Comment: Sorry, that should have read message body for the 'T . ', not subject body; I left it too long to edit the previous comment(s).

Comment: You need to post the *context* of that block. As both Hackerman and I asked, what does base.tpl look like?

Comment: mail_templated/base.tpl looks like this in my virtualenv:  {{ TAG_START_SUBJECT }}{% block subject %}{% endblock %}{{ TAG_END_SUBJECT }}

{{ TAG_START_BODY }}{% block body %}{% endblock %}{{ TAG_END_BODY }}

{{ TAG_START_HTML }}{% block html %}{% endblock %}{{ TAG_END_HTML }}

Comment: If that is not what you mean by context, please can you clarify what you want as I'm not sure I understand what you're really after.

Comment: If you mean context like a Django context where you pass in parameters, then there is no context.  If you mean context as in what is the application, the code happens to slot in to a Django view and is called from there.  However, this is, in my opinion, irrelevant as you can reproduce the error using the code above in a Django shell by running 'python manage.py shell' and inputting my email code as long as you have the my_email.tpl defined in an appropriate location.

Comment: OK, so I've been trying to debug mail_templated and of course there is a context; the {'user':email} parameter to send_mail is a context.  It is used by mail_templated; I just chose an arbitrary key/value pair for it.  I'm not convinced this is causing my issue though.